# how to unwrap optionals, how can i write this code to not have any ? or ! in it, or is it possible?

Tags: swift

I am having a hard time to rewrite this code so that there are no optionals ? in it or force unwrapping ! So far I was able to get it to work but with the optional in the output. I would like the output to not have the optional in it.

```
class CeaserCipher {
    var secret: Int? = 0

    func setSecret(_ maybeString: String?) {
        guard let stringSecret = maybeString else {
            return
        }

        self.secret = Int(stringSecret)
    }
}

let cipher = CeaserCipher()
cipher.setSecret(nil)
print(cipher.secret)

cipher.setSecret("ten")
print(cipher.secret)

cipher.setSecret("125")
print(cipher.secret)
```

Comment: What result do you want when you pass a string that isn't a valid `Int`?

Comment: @rmaddy ah... good question, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: i am trying to just not have this crash, and i did that with the above code but I want to see if it is possible to rewrite this with no ? or ! in the code. but if that is not possible then how do I get rid of the optional in the output?

Comment: Don't avoid `?` in Swift. Learn to embrace the use of optionals and work with them properly.

Comment: You might consider making `CeaserCipher` non-mutable, this way, you're forced to pass a valid value to the constructor

Comment: @rmaddy ok, I was under the impression that it was bad structure to use ? in the code. So, how would I get rid of the optional in the output that this causes?

Comment: @monkey `?` is perfectly ok to use. And in a lot of cases... unavoidable. What is more dangerous to use is `!` which is a "force unwrap". This will crash your code if you try to force unwrap an optional that is nil. Which is probably what you were thinking of :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right. Something that does help in a lot of cases (and is used a lot in Swift) is immutable structs and models. You could make `CeaserCypher` immutable and require that the secret is passed in to the initialiser when creating it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Making the class non-mutable doesn't force you to pass a valid value to the `init.` You would need to make the `init` failable so there would still be an optional involved.

Comment: @rmaddy That depends on the design, if you used `init(string: String)` then you're enforcing the requirement ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer No because the string might not be a valid `Int` which is why you need `init?(string: String)`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I still have so much to learn, how would I make this immutable then. and where would I use the init at, would it be in right after my secret declar or in my function for maybe string.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, they're convert the `String` to an `Int`, missed that, was focused on the `String?`

Comment: I think it should be spelled .[`CaesarCipher`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a cat, there are many ways you might skin it.

You "could" make the cipher immutable by providing a failable constructor, for example...

```
struct CeaserCipher {
    let secret: Int

    init?(string: String) {
        guard let value = Int(string) else { return nil }
        secret = value
    }
}
```

This doesn't stop you needing to deal with optionals, but it means that an instance of `CeaserCipher` will be valid.

The `struct` is focrcing at least one requirement, that you have a non-optional `String`, so you will need to valid that first

So if you did something like...

```
let cipher = CeaserCipher(string: "Bad")
```

`cipher` would be `nil` and you'd need to deal with it, but if you did something like...

```
let cipher = CeaserCipher(string: "123456789")
```

`cipher` would be a valid instance and you could work with it.

Using `guard` and `if let` are important here, as they will allow you to avoid crashing the code, which you would use would depend on your needs.

```
guard let cipher = CeaserCipher(string: "123456789") else {
    // Cipher is invalid, deal with it...
    return
} 
// Valid cipher, continue to work with it
```

or

```
if let cipher = CeaserCipher(string: "123456789") {
    // Valid cipher, continue to work with it
} else {
    // Cipher is invalid, deal with it...or not
}
```

The point of the example is, you will either get a valid instance of `CeaserCipher` or a `nil`, which is "generally" safer then having an instance which is in a invalid state and generally easier to deal with

Comment: Is this the only way of getting rid of the optional in the output from the code I gave? I thought I could use a guard or if let to get rid of it but no luck and so far I am not sure how I would unwrap the optional without force unwrapping.

Comment: No, not really, the problem is, you're passing an optional `String` to the function, which could in turn produce an optional result.  Either you tighten up the requirements or you learn to live with the possibility.  The only "additional" thing you'd need to do is check `cipher.secret` and make sure it's not optional. `if let secret = cipher.secret { print(secret) }`

Comment: where would I put that check? I have tried it in several places, but maybe i am not understanding. I put it right under my let cipher and it just prints the values 0 and nil. Do you know how I would unwrap the optional in the output?

Comment: @monkey You would put it anywhere you might want to `print` the secret, because you need to ensure that's not an optional before you print it